What is the difference between cloning a specific tag of vcpkg and the "builtin-baseline" tag in manifest mode
I am a little bit confused about the builtin-baseline tag in vcpkg.
I clone vcpkg as a submodule with a specific TAG_ID. So what influence does the builtin-baseline tag in the manifest mode still have?
Because when I change it, suddenly it affects some of my modules.
We have the vcpkg TAG, the builtin-baseline AND i can specify a specific version in the vcpkg.json. How do these all play together?
